# Reduce $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times$ to $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Please help me understand this problem:

**Given Problem**: Using the ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/rs \cong \mathbb{Z}/r \times \mathbb{Z}/s$,
  show that we have an isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/rs)^\times \cong
  (\mathbb{Z}/r)^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/s)^\times$ of groups of units (i.e.,
  invertible elements under multiplication).  This allows you to
  compute $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times$ by decomposing $n$ as a product of prime
  powers, and reduces the problem to $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)^\times$.

**My questions on the problem**:

I presume the notation $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times$ refers to the group of non-zero integers modulus $n$ under multiplication. This only forms a group when $n$ is prime. When $n$ is a power of a prime $p^k$, for example $4$, then element $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n$ does not have a multiplicative inverse and $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times$ is not a group.

I don't understand how you can reduce the problem to $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n)^\times$ when that is not a group when $n > 1$.

Comment: $R^{\times}$ denotes the group of units of a ring $R$. So $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is the group of invertible elements mod $n$, that is those that are relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: You're mistaken: $\(mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$ denotes the set of *units*  in the ring $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: So, $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^\times$ would include $\{1,3\}$ but not $0$ or $2$?

Comment: Exactly. The coprimes.